# Electron JS open window when click HTML Button

Tags: electron

I have googled it and it seems like a recurrent task , but I did not find a good solution , Here is my code .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 style="color: red">Todos</h1>
    <button type="button">Todos panel</button>
    <script>
      const btn = document.querySelector('button');
      button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        newtaskwindow();
      });
      function newtaskwindow() {
        const remote = require('electron').remote;
        const BrowserWindow = remote.BrowserWindow;
        const win = new BrowserWindow({
          height: 600,
          width: 800
        });

        win.loadFile('todos.html');
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This does not work .. I want to click the button to open a new child window.

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } = require('electron');

function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  });

  win.loadFile('index.html');
}

const todoWin = () => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 500,
    height: 400,
    modal: true,
    parent: ''
  });

  win.loadFile('todos.html');
};

// Menu
const isMac = process.platform === 'darwin';

const template = [
  ...(isMac
    ? [
        {
          label: 'Demo',
          submenu: [{ role: 'about' }]
        }
      ]
    : []),

  {
    label: 'File',
    submenu: [isMac ? { role: 'close' } : { role: 'quit' }]
  }
];

const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();
});

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
    const value = document.querySelector('input').value;
    ipcRenderer.send('todo:save', value);
    window.close();
  });
```

I did it through ipcRenderer

Answer (score 1):

I see two things...

In **main.js** add `enableRemoteModule` and `contextIsolation`

```js
function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      contextIsolation:false

    }
  });

  win.loadFile('index.html');
}
```

in **index.html** you use `button.addEventListener` instead of `btn.addEventListener`. Change it.

```html
    <script>
      const btn = document.querySelector('button');
      btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        newtaskwindow();
      });
      function newtaskwindow() {
        const remote = require('electron').remote;
        const BrowserWindow = remote.BrowserWindow;
        const win = new BrowserWindow({
          height: 600,
          width: 800
        });

        win.loadFile('todos.html');
      }
    </script>
```

That way should work.

---

**WARNING**
As stated in Electron's documentation [`remote`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/remote#remote) module is deprecated. You are encouraged to use [`IPC`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main#sending-messages) in order to execute code on `main` on request of `renderer`.